# How to set a textbox input length

Tags: vb6

Using VB6

using Textbox in my form.

I want to limit the Input in the textbox, so maximum value should be 6.
User should enter up to six chars otherwise it should show error message

```
Button1.click

if Length(textbox1.text) > 6 then
  enter only six chars
else if Length(textbox1.text) < 6 then
  enter up to six chars
```

How do I make the code for the above condition.

Comment: Why give error message,it would be best to prevent entering more than 6 characters. Have a look at MaxLength property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you're getting close!

First ... use the `Len` function, not `Length`, which doesn't exist.

Second ... you can use the function `MsgBox` to display an error message.

Putting it all together:

```
If Len(TextBox1.Text) < 6 Then
   MsgBox "Too short!"
Else If Len(TextBox1.Text) > 6 Then
   MsgBox "Too long!"
End If
```

Answer (score 12):

Textboxes in VB6 have a `MaxLength` property.  Set it to 6 and then the user **can't** enter more than 6.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Text1_Change()
    If Len(Text1) > 6 Then
        Text1 = " "    
        MsgBox "Not more than six"    
        Text1.SetFocus    
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The question was for when the text was less than or greater than the 6 characters. Your answer only handles one of these cases.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could set the MaxLength property to the desired value.

As for the warning, you could place it in the keyUp/Down or keypress events:
If Len(Text1.Text) = Text1.MaxLength Then MsgBox ("WARNING!"), vbExclamation

Answer (score 0):

' working in vb.net

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
              TextBox1.MaxLength = 6
    End Sub
```

'in vb6

```
Private Sub Text1_Change()
    If Len(Text1.text) > 6 Then
        text1.enabled=false  
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Text1_DoubleClick
   text1.enable=true
   text1.text=""
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this code

```
If Len(Me.txtusername.Text) And Len(Me.txtpassword.Text)< 5 Then
          Call MsgBox("Login failed !, password character must at list 5 and above")

Else
          Call MsgBox("Error occurred ! Password did not match!")
End If
```