# Limit entries in textbox in userform to certain values

Tags: excel, vba

I need to limit the textbox in a userform to accept values from 50000 to 59999; and also to accept a blank entry.

In case these conditions are not satisfied the userform should appear again.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506058/how-to-set-a-textbox-input-length

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a textbox input length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506058/how-to-set-a-textbox-input-length)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub TextBox3_AfterUpdate()
If TextBox3.Value < 50000 Or TextBox3.Value > 59999 Or TextBox3.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox ("worng entry")
    TextBox3.Value = ""
    Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That looks similar to existing answer. Can you explain what's different please and why this is better? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should go in the button the user clicks trying to submit. Run this before doing anything - If your criteria is met, the code will stop and go back to form.

I'm guessing you will also want to bring attention to non-numeric entries as well.

```
If Textbox.Value < 50000 or TextBox.Value > 59999 or Not IsNumeric(TextBox) Then
    Textbox.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Invalid Entry"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

First thing that comes to my mind to allow a blank entry is to just insert a space to give the appearance of a blank entry, but I am sure there is a better way to do this.

```
If Len(TextBox.Value) = 0 Then TextBox.Value = Chr(32)
```

Comment: will this cover the blank entry input??

Comment: Test it and you tell me :)

Comment: I'm getting the invalid entry if the textbox is blank

Comment: Still doesn't work. Still get the invalid entry message.